# Run a tool on LAMP server as service

Tags: service, lamp

I have installed and configured LAMP to run on my Ubuntu 11.10. Now I need to set up a tool to be run on this LAMP server. The tool can be run by a jar file and there is also a shell script to run it. Contents of script are:

```
#Script must be in the same directory as tool.jar
java -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -Xmx900m -jar `dirname $0`/tool.jar $*
```

I have copied the tool directory in the /var/www/ folder but do not know what to do next. Specifically I need to add link on my Localhost page to run this tool. Expecting help.

AK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: I am being able to run simple ls commands using a php script like this:  '<?php
  $output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
  ?>'  But the program which needs to be invoked is GUI based. My script to invoke program:  '#!/usr/bin/php -q  <?php  exec('./igv.jar')  ?>'  Though this script runs the program from terminal but when run from browser fails to load program, shows no error.